# Creating migrations for a Django project that does not have any migrations already

Tags: django, django-migrations

I am working for a client with a 13 year old Django project.  When they built the project migrations were not implemented so the project currently lacks migrations.  I have tried creating migrations and then doing a datadump and loaddata into a new database to test them out.  I am running into all sorts of errors and would like to start fresh.

So my question is this.  What steps should I take to implement migrations in the project so that we can move forward using migrations?  The django version has been updated to 3.0.5 and there are a number of GenericForeignKeys used, which might make this extra tricky.  When creating the migrations originally I was told to use the fake tag but don't completely understand what this means.

Any help in the steps that I should take would be appreciated.  For the sake of privacy/security for the client I don't want to just share a ton of their code but can share parts of it if it helps someone determine the steps that I should take.

For reference.  After creating migration files originally and then trying the dumdata/loaddata commands I typically get an error saying that there are duplicate entries relating to contenttypes or duplicate entries for django_site domains.  The client has domains set up depending on where in the world they are logging in from so the site "name" is unique but the "domain" is the same.

```
(1062, "Duplicate entry 'www.example.com' for key 'django_site.django_site_domain_a2e37b91_uniq'")
```

Answer (score 0):

- If you are talking about working on local, simply, delete all the migrations (except `migrations/__init__.py`.) and `makemigrations` again.
- If you are on production, you are safe to use `--fake` once.
- You are OK also to change the old migrations if you know how to do deal with migrations, and if it is few files.

**I have answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70050563/modify-django-migrations-file-or-use-fake-flag/70059752#70059752).**

Comment: There arn't any migration files as of yet though.